# Messaging.SingleEmailMessage method compiles anonymously but not in a class

Tags: apex, email, singleemailmessage, compile-error, execute-anonymous

Here's the issue:

I'm trying to use the method `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage.setEntityAttachments(List<Id>)` in a class, but it won't compile. However, when I run the same code in anonymous apex, the code compiles, runs, and the `getEntityAttachments`attribute of the SingleEmailMessage is set as expected.

Here's the class I've written to test this issue. It will only compile if you keep the line `emailToSend.setEntityAttachments(attachmentIds);`commented out:

```
public with sharing class MessageAttachmentsTest {
public MessageAttachmentsTest() {

    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

    for(integer i = 0; i<5;i++){

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage emailToSend = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

        String subject = 'Subject';
        String body = 'Body';
        List<Id> attachmentIds = new List<Id>{'068630000002jOSAAY', '068630000002jOXAAY'};
        Id whatId = 'a0f63000000aF2EAAU';
        List<String> bccAddresses = new List<String>{'bcc@example.com','bcc2@example.com'};
        List<String> ccAddresses = new List<String>{'cc@example.com','cc2@example.com'};


        //set email values
        emailToSend.setSubject(subject);
        emailToSend.setHTMLBody(body);
        emailToSend.setWhatId(whatId);
        emailToSend.setBCCAddresses(bccAddresses);
        emailToSend.setCcAddresses(ccAddresses);
        //********************WILL NOT COMPILE IF THE NEXT LINE IS UNCOMMENTED OUT****************
        //emailToSend.setEntityAttachments(attachmentIds);
        emailList.add(emailToSend);

    }

    System.debug(emailList[0]);}

}
```

Here's the anonymous apex, running on the same API version, that compiles, runs, and successfully sets the `getEntityAttachments`attribute as can be seen in the system debug log:

```
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

    for(integer i = 0; i<5;i++){

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage emailToSend = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

        String subject = 'Subject';
        String body = 'Body';       
        List<Id> attachmentIds = new List<Id>{'068630000002jOSAAY', '068630000002jOXAAY'};
        Id whatId = 'a0f63000000aF2EAAU';
        List<String> bccAddresses = new List<String>{'bcc@example.com','bcc2@example.com'};
        List<String> ccAddresses = new List<String>{'cc@example.com','cc2@example.com'};


        //set email values
        emailToSend.setSubject(subject);
        emailToSend.setHTMLBody(body);
        emailToSend.setWhatId(whatId);
        emailToSend.setBCCAddresses(bccAddresses);
        emailToSend.setCcAddresses(ccAddresses);
        emailToSend.setEntityAttachments(attachmentIds);
        emailList.add(emailToSend);

    }

    System.debug(emailList[0]);
```

Excerpt from the debug log:

```
14:28:33:005 USER_DEBUG [27]|DEBUG|Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[getBccAddresses=(bcc@example.com, bcc2@example.com);getCcAddresses=(cc@example.com, cc2@example.com);getCharset=null;getEntityAttachments=(068630000002jOSAAY, 068630000002jOXAAY);getFileAttachments=null;getHtmlBody=Body;getInReplyTo=null;getOptOutPolicy=SEND;getOrgWideEmailAddressId=null;getPlainTextBody=null;getReferences=null;getTargetObjectId=null;getTemplateId=null;getToAddresses=null;getWhatId=a0f63000000aF2EAAU;isTreatBodiesAsTemplate=false;isTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient=true;isUserMail=false;]
```

What I've already tried:

- Using the latest version API for my class (34.0)
- Checked to make sure none of my classes are named the same as system     classes
- Tried sending the list as a string instead of a list of ids
- Checked to make sure content version exists

Why won't the class compile with `emailToSend.setEntityAttachments(attachmentIds);`?

Comment: You're not giving us the most critical piece of info. What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The newest API Version is *not* 34.0, but rather 38.0, in which this method will compile. It looks like this method was added in **`API Version 35.0`**, as it compiles for any version 35.0 and above. Simple class to demonstrate:

```
public class EmailAttachmentDemo
{
    public static void buildEmail()
    {
        new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage().setEntityAttachments(new List<Id>());
    }
}
```

In version 35.0 and up, it compiles, but in version 34.0, it gives the compile error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Messaging.SingleEmailMessage].setEntityAttachments(List)

Comment: Oh damn that worked! You have earned my love! Drink's on me the next time you're in NYC!